# Is there a way to perform SVD in a sequential manner?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, matrix, svd, matrix-decomposition

My neurology experiment has a spike detector outputting `40` sample long spike waveforms.

I'm using a dictionary method for sorting the spikes in real time. To obtain the dictionary at start of program, I want to use all the spikes detected in the first `30` seconds and perform an `SVD` of the `Nx40` matrix, where `N` is the number of spikes detected in the first `30` seconds.

Is there an algorithm which can perform this `Nx40` `SVD` in a sequential or iterative method or perhaps in smaller batches. The expected spiking rate means my program cannot store all the 30s worth of spike waveforms (rows of the matrix) in memory.

Comment: How big is $N$?  How much memory do you have?

Comment: N is likely to be in the range of 300-500. I'm running this on an 64 bit Ubuntu machine with 8GB of RAM, the modules are in C++.

Comment: You're running out of memory trying to find the SVD of a 500 by 40 matrix?  That's absurdly small to be running out of memory.

Comment: Sorry,  I forget to mention it is a multielectrode situation. 18 tetrodes = 18x4 = 72 such SVDs.

Comment: OK, so you actually have a matrix of size 500 by (40 times 18 time 4).  That's a matrix of size 500 by 2880.  This is still very small.